# Deriving the Formulas for the Weighted Average

Tags: probability, derivatives, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to learn more about the inverse-variance weighting method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting). Here is come context to my question.

**Part 1:**

Suppose have Random Variables $X_1, X_2, ... X_N$ . Let's say that for any of these Random Variables we have a sample size of $n_i$ and a sample mean of  $\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2, \dots, \bar{x}_n$. Suppose if we "magically" knew the population variance for all $X_1, X_2, ... X_N$, that is $V(X_i) = \sigma_i^2$ . That is, we assume that each $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma_i^2)$. It is reasonable to assume that each $\bar{x}_i$ has a Normal Distribution by virtue of the Central Limit Theorem.  We are interested in estimating $\mu$ with some estimator $\mu_w$.

Given this information, suppose we wanted to estimate  $\mu_w$  in such a way, such that the resulting variance $Var(\mu_w)$ is smallest. We can consider this problem as an optimization problem where we minimize $Var(\mu_w)$ and can solve this using the Lagrange Method:

$$ \mu_w = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \bar{x_i}}{\sum w_i}$$

where $w_i$ represents the weights assigned to each sample mean.

To minimize the variance of the weighted mean, we can formulate the problem as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Minimize:} & V = w_1^2 \sigma_1^2 + w_2^2 \sigma_2^2 + \dots + w_n^2 \sigma_n^2 \\
& \text{Subject to:} & w_1 + w_2 + \dots + w_n = 1
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
L = V - \lambda(w_1 + w_2 + \dots + w_n - 1)
$$

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial w_i} = 2w_i\sigma_i^2 - \lambda = 0 \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, \dots, n
$$

$$
w_i = \frac{\lambda}{2\sigma_i^2} \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, \dots, n
$$

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = w_1 + w_2 + \dots + w_n - 1 = 0
$$

$$
\frac{\lambda}{2\sigma_1^2} + \frac{\lambda}{2\sigma_2^2} + \dots + \frac{\lambda}{2\sigma_n^2} - 1 = 0
$$

$$
\lambda = 2(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_2^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2})^{-1}
$$

$$
w_i = (\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_2^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2})^{-1}\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}  \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, \dots, n
$$

The resulting values of $w_i$ will produce the minimum variance of $\mu_{w}$ and is a well known result called "Inverse-Variance Weighting" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting).

**Part 2:**

Now suppose we have a more realistic situation where we have sample means $\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2, \dots, \bar{x}_n$ and only sample variances $s_1^2, s_2^2 ... s_n^2$. Let's assume that each $s_i^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma_i^2$.  As such, we have a similar problem where we assume that each $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma_i^2)$. We are still interested in estimating $\mu$ with some estimator $\mu_w$.

Although this situation is similar to Part 1, it is still more complicated given that we are dealing with  $s_i^2$ instead of $\sigma_i^2$. To find out the minimum variance estimator $\mu_w$, we now need to take into consideration the sampling distribution of  $s_i^2$. The following paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/3001633) shows how to do this:

Each $w_i$ maintains a similar formula:

$$\hat{w}_i = \left(\frac{1}{s_1^2} + \frac{1}{s_2^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{s_n^2}\right)^{-1}\frac{1}{s_i^2}  \quad \text{for } i = 1, 2, \dots, n
$$

But the Variance of  $\mu_w$ based on these weights is now:

$$\hat{V}(\mu_{\text{weighted}}) = \left(\frac{1}{\sum \frac{1}{s_i^2}}\right) \left[ 1 + 4 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( w_i(1-w_i) \frac{1}{n_i}\right)\right]
 $$

If I understand correctly, the above estimator is the minimum variance estimator based on  $s_i^2$ instead of $\sigma_i^2$. (**??? clarification needed ???**)

**Part 3:** Finally, this is where my question comes in. Now, let's suppose we have an even more realistic situation in which we have sample means $\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2, \dots, \bar{x}_n$, sample variances $s_1^2, s_2^2 ... s_n^2$ - but this time $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$

I tried to  myself to derive an estimator for Part 3 where this requirement is not present i.e. $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$. For  example, suppose we have two sample $n_1, n_2$ with sample means $\bar{x}_1, \bar{x}_2$ and sample variances $s_1^2, s_2^2$. We can write:

$$\mu_w = w_1(\bar{x_1}) + w_2(\bar{x_2}) \quad \text{where } w_1 + w_2 = 1
$$

$$\hat{V}(\mu_w) = \frac{\sum(x_{1i} - \mu_w)^2 + \sum(x_{2i} - \mu_w)^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 1}$$

$$\hat{V}(\mu_w) = \frac{\sum(x_{1i}^2) - 2\mu_w \sum(x_{1i}) + n_1\mu_w^2 + \sum(x_{2i}^2) - 2\mu_w \sum(x_{2i}) + n_2\mu_w^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 1}$$

After further manipulation and simplification:

$$\hat{V}(\mu) = \frac{(n_1-1)s_1^2 + n_1\bar{x}_1^2 + (n_2-1)s_2^2 + n_2\bar{x}_2^2 + (n_1+n_2)\mu_w^2 - 2\mu_w(n_1\bar{x}_1 + n_2\bar{x}_2)}{n_1+n_2-1}
$$

Now, if we take the partial derivatives of $\hat{V}(\mu)$ with respect to $w_1$ and $w_2$, and then set these to 0 - we get that $w_1 = n_1/(n_1+ n_2)$ and $w_2 = n_2/(n_1 + n_2)$. Furthermore, I then took the second partial derivative of $\hat{V}(\mu)$ with respect to $w_1$ and $w_2$ and observed that both of these second partial derivatives were positive - indicating that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are indeed minimum solutions. The above derivation can also be extended for more than two sample means.

**My Question:**

- I was able to derive a minimum variance estimator in **Part 3** which did not assume that all means were equal - as a matter of fact, in **Part 3**, it seems like a minimum variance estimator was derived without any assumptions whatsoever! Looking back, I also notice that **Part 1** and **Part 2** also did not seem to require  $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma_i^2)$. Thus, I don't understand why **Part 1** and **Part 2** require each $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma_i^2)$ ?
- An interesting note, in **Part 3** it seems like the variances are not present in the weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ at all! Thus, is it possible that the Inverse-Variance Weighting Scheme for unequal means (i.e. **Part 3**) results in weights solely based on relative sample sizes (i.e.  $n_1,n_2$) ?
- And finally, just to re-iterate one more time - in the situation where $\bar{x}_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$, is it true that the mean estimator with the lowest variance is equivalent to what I have derived in **Part 3**?

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! OP here - I wish someone would tell me the reason why this question was downvoted so I can learn and improve it. Thank you!

Comment: This is unclear to me. If in Part 3 the different samples are drawn from distributions with different means, then which mean are you trying to estimate?